# Trouble accessing dual ranges

Tags: excel, range, vba

I found the majority of the following code online and it works awesome for me. The part I have added is the creation of the second range rngUniques2 and the use of that range for some string manipulation. The problem I am having is that when I try to access that range, it is not pulling the correct value except for the first time. I am thinking I am using the counter wrong, but I have not been able to get it correct. I know the range has the correct values in it as I did a For Each Cell debug print.

```
Sub Extract_All_Data()

'this macro assumes that your first row of data is a header row.
'will copy all filtered rows from one worksheet, to another blank workbook
'each unique filtered value will be copied to it's own sheet

'Variables used by the macro
Dim wbOrig, wbDest As Workbook
Dim rngFilter As Range, rngUniques, rngUniques2 As Range
Dim cell As Range, counter As Integer
Dim xValue, OutValue As String

 ' Prompt user to choose file and open it
MsgBox "Please select the file that will be split."
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select the file that will be split.", FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

If strFileToOpen = "False" Then
    MsgBox "No file selected.", vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wbOrig = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFileToOpen)
End If


Sheets("HTPN").Activate

' Set the filter range (from A1 to the last used cell in column A)
Set rngFilter = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With rngFilter

    ' Filter column A to show only one of each item (uniques) in column A
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True

    ' Set a variable to the Unique values (one for ClientID and one for Client Name)
    Set rngUniques = Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rngUniques2 = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' Clear the filter
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

End With

' Create a new workbook with a sheet for each unique value
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = rngUniques.Count
Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3

' Filter, Copy, and Paste each unique to its' own sheet in the new workbook
For Each cell In rngUniques

    counter = counter + 1

    'NOTE - this filter is on column A (field:=1), to change
    'to a different column you need to change the field number
    rngFilter.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value

    ' Copy and paste the filtered data to it's unique sheet
    rngFilter.Resize(, 30).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=wbDest.Sheets(counter).Range("A1")

    ' Name the destination sheet
    ' Strip Client name to extract the AU #
    xValue = rngUniques2(counter, 1).Value

    Debug.Print xValue

    OutValue = ""

    For xIndex = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
        If (VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1) <> "-") Then
                If VBA.IsNumeric(VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)) Then
                    OutValue = OutValue & VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)
                End If
        Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next

    wbDest.Sheets(counter).Name = cell.Value & " - " & OutValue
    wbDest.Sheets(counter).Cells.Columns.AutoFit

Next cell

rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    

End Sub
```

EDIT TO EXPLAIN

Sample data:

A     B

1     A

1     A

1     A

2     B

2     B

3     C

3     C

3     C

3     C

4     D

4     D

4     D

The program copies all rows of each unique item in column A to separate tabs and attempts to name the tab correctly. It is the naming of the tab that is causing me troubles. I am trying to get the tab name in the following format "A value - B value", so for the above example, there would be four tabs named:

1 - A

2 - B

3 - C

4 - D

rngUniques contains the unique values from column A and rngUniques2 contains the corresponding values from column B. I am trying to read from both ranges in the same For Each Loop, but it is not accessing the correct data in rngUniques2. For example when I run the macro, it would name the tabs:

1 - A

2 - A

3 - B

4 - C

The small sample size above makes it look like it is only one item off, but it gets further off as it goes. My actual data creates 110 separate tabs. I am assuming the error comes from the way I am trying to access the data below.

```
xValue = rngUniques2(counter, 1).Value
```

How would I progress through the data of another range while using a For Each Loop on a different range?

Comment: Define "not pulling the correct value". Show what you expect the value to be, and what it actually comes up as.

Comment: Lets say rngUniques2 is a table of the alphabet, i.e. 26 cells with a single letter each, and rngUniques is a list of numbers 1 to 26. The first time thru the For loop it will correctly pull "A" from rngUniques2. After that it will progress thru the range at a different step than rngUniques. For example it will be something like this: 1-A  2-A  3-B  4-C  5-C etc...  You can see how the second range gets away from the first in the loop.

Comment: So far, I have been able to brute force this to work for me by just combining column A and B into column A. The macro works fine when just using rngUniques by itself. However, there are 15000+ lines in the file, so I know it is not the most efficient approach, especially since it has to do the string manipulation for each row.

Comment: I must confess I still don't understand the issue. Please edit your question to include all details include a sample of your data and the expected vs actual outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to brute force this to work for me by just combining column A and B into column A.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks, that last edit does help quite a bit.

Final clarification: If the text in column A is always, say "2", is the text in column B always, say, "B"? Or are there times when ColumnA might be 2 but column B might be "C"? Because to me, I think you are overcomplicating things by doing any checking of rnguniques2 at all.

Assuming Column B is the same for each unique column A value, you can delete all references to rnguniques2 except for the initial "set = column B", and then when setting the name of the sheet, just go "rnguniques(counter,1).value & " - " & rnguniques(counter,2).value"

I can't really see the point of this section of the code here:

```
xValue = rngUniques2(counter, 1).Value

Debug.Print xValue

OutValue = ""

For xIndex = 1 To VBA.Len(xValue)
    If (VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1) <> "-") Then
            If VBA.IsNumeric(VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)) Then
                OutValue = OutValue & VBA.Mid(xValue, xIndex, 1)
            End If
    Else: Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Column B will always be the same for unique value in A. The reason for the code above, is because column B is actually a long company name that includes an ID number. The code strips out the number only as this is actually what I need to put on the tab name. This is why I needed to be able to work with that value by itself. This also means that I cannot just concatenate the values like you suggested.

Comment: @Jay All of these details that I've needed to pull from you have been necessary to answer your question. Please re-edit your question to include a sample of your data **including the way it is actually formatted in your source workbooks**, along with all specific assumptions and notes that have been posted as comments along the way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, I am going to just use the workaround that I mentioned above. It is a little inefficient, but it gets the job done. I needed to hve this working today, so I am satisfied with it.